# <!--more--> being ignored when WordPress content is displayed

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to write a plugin that will take page id's and return a preview of the page. Here's my code:

```
function page_preview($atts,$pageid = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
"pageid" => '0'
), $atts));
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=' . $pageid . '' );
global $more;    
$more = 0;   
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    $title=get_the_title();
    $thumbnail=get_the_post_thumbnail( $pageid, 'preview' );
    $content=get_the_content();
}
} 
return '<div class="callout">' . 
'<h4>' . 
$title . 
'</h4>' . 
$thumbnail . 
$content . '<a href="' . 
get_the_permalink($pageid) . 
'">Continue reading</a></div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'pagepreview', 'page_preview' );
```

and it gets called on wpadmin editor like so:
    [pagepreview pageid=11][pagepreview pageid=13][pagepreview pageid=8054]
i.e., that would display a page preview for each of those page ids.

The "more" doesn't work.

```
global $more;    
$more = 0;
```

usually fixes this issue, but it's not in my case. Can anyone see what I"m doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the full content because

`$content=get_the_content();`

is not applying `the_content()` filters, and `$more=0` must be on a line after `$the_query->the_post();` inside the while loop. Change your while loop to this:

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    $more=0;
    $title=get_the_title();
    $thumbnail=get_the_post_thumbnail( $pageid, 'preview' );
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
    $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
}
```

See [get_the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Alternative_Usage) and [read more in pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#How_to_use_Read_More_in_Pages) on the WordPress Codex for where I sourced this.

Comment: Thank you. Tried this but still doesn't work; I've put $more = 0 everywhere with no success yet...

Comment: What output are you getting from the plugin? Are you getting the full content of the post (above and below the more tag) or something else?

Comment: Getting the full output of the post, above and below.

Comment: I've updated my answer. This shortcode is now working on my WordPress installation.

Comment: No mine, unfortunately. I was so psyched when I saw your answer, but it still refuses to honor the more tag. Code is at http://pastebin.com/hSjfdL4G

Comment: `$more=0` must be on a line after `$the_query->the_post();`. I'll update my answer in a minute to reflect this.

Comment: hate to bug you VV, but any luck?

Comment: I updated my answer to be more clear (and include the whole while loop). If this does work for you please [accept it as the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that I know it worked for you.